# How do you move text from one form to another? c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I basically need to convert text that the user enters into a textbox and then put it into another form. Anyone know how to do this? This is in VB c#.

Comment: i bet no one on SO have ever heard about this new language :)

Comment: Your question is not clearly written. What does "convert text" mean? You will get better answers and response if you formulate your questions clearly, precise and best abstract.

Comment: No I said I'm using visual basic 2010 with c# programming language

Answer (score 1):

Assuming WinForms and assuming your two Forms are in the same solution (VB.NET):

```
Form2.TextBox1.Text = Form1.TextBox1.Text
```

Comment: Condition : TextBox1 should be public

Comment: @RajeevKumar - TextBoxes in WinForms are `Friend` by default so is accessible by code within the same process - I have editing my answer to clarify this assumption

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing this value in constructor of Form2 when calling it through Form1